# How to make tap interfaces persistent after reboot?

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, network-interface

Some tasks requires having tap interfaces **configured + assign ownership**.
So, I am doing it manually:

```
sudo tuntap -u <username>
sudo ifconfig tap0 up
sudo ip a a 192.168.1.1/24 dev tap0
```

or using

```
ip tuntap add dev tap0 mode tap user <username>
```

How can I make tap interfaces configuration peristent after reboots without adding these commands to a shell script and add to startup

What I have in mind is doing it through **/etc/network/interfaces** like the following:

```
iface tap1 inet static
address 192.168.1.121
netmask 255.255.255.0
pre-up /usr/sbin/tunctl -u ajn -t tap1
```

But for some reason, it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I cannot see, for the life of me, why this question should be down-voted. It is clear, correct, it has a well-defined answer. I have upvoted it.

You are using obsolete utilities like tunctl, you should use *ip* instead. The correct stanza for */etc/network/interfaces* is:

```
    iface tap1 inet manual 
    pre-up ip tuntap add tap1 mode tap user root
    pre-up ip addr add 192.168.1.121/24 dev tap1
    up ip link set dev tap1 up
    post-up ip route del 192.168.1.0/24 dev tap1 
    post-up ip route add 192.168.1.121/32 dev tap1
    post-down ip link del dev tap1
```

Your mistake was in using *static* instead of *manual*. The reason is that, since you are trying to give to the virtual interface an address in the same subnet as your main interfae (wlan0/eth0), when it tries automatically to add a local route,

```
    ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev tap1
```

it finds that such a route already exists, and it complains. If you use *manual* instead of static, you are allowed to delete this route, which is of course useless.

Also, you should add a route

```
     ip route add 192.168.1.121/32 dev tap1
```

to inform your kernel that there is an exception to the route

```
     ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0/wlan0
```

That's all.

Comment: Something doesn't work for me here on ubuntu 17.10: my tun0 is not created - service networking status says that interface `tun0` does not exist. Here's the interfaces file if anyone cares to take a look: https://gist.github.com/velis74/ab75a46893eaed8bd08b8c6292b2737a

Comment: @velis Your new interface is called **tap0**, not *tun0*, that´s why it is not found. Please notice that *tun* and *tap* interfaces are fundamentally different, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TUN/TAP,  which one do you wish to create?

Comment: Yes, it's called tap0. This answer is about creating a tap device, not a tun one. I fail to see how this can be the cause of my failure. The pre-up add device command executes perfectly from command line.

Comment: Turns out I was only missing an `auto tap0` stanza. Gist updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few more steps you might need to do:

1. Add a new routing table
   Edit /etc/iproute2/rt_tables to add a new routing table. Call it routing table “rt2”  and set its preferences to 1:

```
    55     local
    254     main
    253     default
    0       unspec
    1       rt2
```

2. As explained in the previous answer, create a tap interface, but then you need to configure the new routing tables, and set routing rules. Add to /etc/network/interfaces:

```
   #create a tap interface and make it persistent
    iface tap1 inet manual 
    pre-up ip tuntap add tap1 mode tap user root
    pre-up ip addr add 192.168.1.121/24 dev tap1
    up ip link set dev tap1 up
    post-up ip route del 192.168.1.0/24 dev tap1 
    post-up ip route add 192.168.1.121/32 dev tap1
    post-down ip link del dev tap1

    #configure the new routing table so that network 192.168.1.0 can be reached through the tap1 interface
    post-up ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev tap1 src 192.168.1.121 table rt2

    #set the default gateway to be 192.168.1.10
    post-up ip route add default via 192.168.1.10 dev tap1 table rt2

    #set rules so that traffic from and to 192.168.1.121 use the rt2 routing table 
    post-up ip rule add from 192.168.1.121/24 table rt2
    post-up ip rule add to 192.168.1.121/24 table rt2
```

```
sudo ifup tap1
```

To test it:

```
ip route list table rt2
ip rule show
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the Simple Steps:

**Step 1**: **Install** uml-utilities using

```
sudo apt-get install uml-utilities
```

**Step 2**: Add the below commands in **/etc/network/interfaces**

```
auto tap0
iface tap0 inet static
address 192.168.100.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
pre-up /usr/bin/tunctl -t tap0
```

**Step 3**:  **Reboot** the Machine and execute the command `ifconfig`
Changes you've made it should reflect