# Can't create tap interface on Debian

Tags: linux, networking, debian

I am trying to create persistent tap interface.

I have edited /etc/network/interfaces according to solution in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/854401/how-to-make-tap-interfaces-persistent-after-reboot) question

```
iface tap1 inet manual 
pre-up ip tuntap add tap1 mode tap user root
pre-up ip addr add 192.168.1.121/24 dev tap1
up ip link set dev tap1 up
post-up ip route del 192.168.1.0/24 dev tap1 
post-up ip route add 192.168.1.121/32 dev tap1
post-down ip link del dev tap1
```

then I am restarting network services

```
 sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

and there is no `tap1` device in `ip a` output.

I've also tried more simple edit of /etc/network/interfaces, just basic setup

```
pre-up tunctl -t tap0 -u root
pre-up ip link set dev tap0 up
```

but still there is no tap0 interface after restart.

Can anyone suggest what am I doing wrong?

Comment: A [tap interface](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/tuntap.txt) is a network packet endpoint for **user space software**. You don't create it in `/etc/network/interfaces`, the **software** creates it. So "creating a persistent tap interface" makes no sense. What do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: @dirkt I want a network interface to provide for qemu virtaul machine, currently I feed qemu with net-up script which creates tap interface every time I start qemu, but I want to create it just one time. And I do not need bridged connection, I want local network between host and qemu with no Internet access. Also I don't want to redirect ports, I need to have real network address.

Comment: qemu is the software that creates the tap interface, so the tap interface will created exactly when you start qemu, and one for each instance of qemu you run. No way around that. Maybe some of the other [qemu network backends](http://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Networking#Network_backend_types) will work better for you? You can also [automate the network configuration](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Networking) on the host side.